# Search into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have imported a CSV to fill a multidimensional array. `$arrCSV`.

```
<?php     
  $foundOneMatchingRow = FALSE;
  foreach ($arrCSV as $row) {
    if (strpos($row['5'], $val) !== FALSE && strlen($row['5']) > 4) {
      $foundOneMatchingRow = TRUE;
      echo $row['6'];
    }
  }
?>
```

The above code outputs from the value of `$val = $_GET['menu'];` which is done buy the URL.

I would like to make a search if possible please based on words in `$row['6'];`.

There will be a search on the page which will pass the search to the URL.

Which would look something like http://example.com/search.php?val=dogs

So the code would look for ANYTHING that relates to dog in `$row [6]`

I hope I have been clear. Any gudiance would be more than welcome. I am testing everything now.

Thank you

Comment: Start by looking at PHP's array_filter() function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: A minus for asking a question. You are aware that there are people with novice level of PHP here..

Comment: Don't know why somebody downvoted, it's a valid question (though it's been answered a few times in the past in various guises)... giving a +1 to offset

Comment: @Mark Baker - Thank you, I did look really. But I know how the above code works. I am not looking for someone to give me the answer. No No, I want to learn. But I have done some advanced things and I have forgot the basic foundation. At the moment I have an online course (Lynda) to learn the basics and grow. But I have to work for my clients and put food on the table. I am starting with your tip stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (strpos($row['6'], $val) !== FALSE)` will evaluate to **true** if `$row['6']` contains "dog" (if `$val`'s value is "dog"). That is, will evaluate to **true** as well if the string in `$row['6']` is "bulldog" or "whateverdogwhatever".

BTW, why do you need this condition: `strlen($row['5']) > 4`? (which I guess should be at least `strlen($row['6']) > 4` if you search on `$row['6']`).

Something else: aren't you confusing strings and integers? Maybe `if (strpos($row['6'], $val) !== FALSE)` should be `if (strpos($row[6], $val) !== FALSE)`?

EDIT

I would suggest to define constants for your CSV columns, for readability.

What about for example:

```
define('CSV_ID', 5);
define('CSV_TEXT', 6);

//...
foreach ($arrCSV as $row) {
  if (strpos($row[CSV_TEXT], $val) !== FALSE && strlen($row[CSV_ID]) > 4) {
    //...
    echo $row[CSV_TEXT];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I am looking into them. I can answer one part now :) `strlen($row['5']) > 4` - because the first 4 chars are ID Key and the CSV is populated with 200 records but only 24 are fully populated.

Comment: What exactly the 5th and 6th columns of your CSV file contain?

Comment: Is this correct - A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script. In other words once a constant has been defined it cannot changed at all?

Comment: Column 5 is the category, Column 6 is the Title e.g (Animal, How to love your dog)

Comment: You can change your constant values between script executions, however it may be more convenient (if columns index can change), that your first CSV line contains "column codes" as strings, and reuse them in your PHP script, allowing to fetch data whatever being the column order.

Comment: BTW, I still don't understand why you need `strlen($row['5']) > 4`. The beginning of the "category" values contains IDs? Some rows don't contain ID and you don't want to process them?

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand. Thank you... I understand the logic in your code. I am going to try to make it without look at yours and test my logic. Thank you Frosty Z

Comment: I have noticed that http://example.com/search.php?val=dogs vs http://example.com/search.php?val=Dogs. Is there a way to ignore if it is lower or upper case. Thank you.